# Compiler through command line

Tags: compiler

Using putty, I want to manage compiler mode through command line, but the answer received is always the compiler help:

```
myuser@serv01 [~]# php public_html/shell/compiler.php state
Content-type: text/html

Usage:  php -f compiler.php -- [options]

state         Show Compilation State
compile       Run Compilation Process
clear         Disable Compiler include path and Remove compiled files
enable        Enable Compiler include path
disable       Disable Compiler include path
help          This help
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/12996/when-should-i-use-the-magento-compiler

not answered yet, but it will say "No, never use the compiler as it has absolutely no case, where you have benefits, if you use current php with current opCache"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue related to php configuration. Magento shell script uses `$_SERVER['argv']` variables to run particular shell script (see shell/abstract.php). You should enable `register_argc_argv` setting in `php.ini` if php is not running in CLI mode.

```
register_argc_argv = On
```

**ADDITIONAL**
Create `test.php` file and add these lines for debugging:

```
echo php_sapi_name();//this should be printed as "cli"
print_r($_SERVER['argv']);// this should print out arguments
```

And run the script `php -f test.php some extra args`

If no results try to run script following:
php -cli public_html/shell/compiler.php state

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have added that row to a php.ini file in shell folder. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: @perissf don't add this line, search for this line and change the value, restart apache server and run the script like php -f public_html/shell/compiler.php state

Comment: It works with php -cli option