# Magento compiler COMPILER_COLLECT_PATH

Tags: performance, compiler

we enabled compiler in backend. If you set to enabled then the file /includes/config.php changes to

```
define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');
#define('COMPILER_COLLECT_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'stat');
```

Now I see some posts also about uncommeting the second line
http://www.expertwebadvisor.com/manually-enable-disabled-the-compiler-in-magento/

**question:** but what does COMPILER_COLLECT_PATH do? and why is it not uncommented when I enable compile?

Many thanks

Comment: Just as a short hint: [When should I use the Magento Compiler](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/12996/when-should-i-use-the-magento-compiler) :-)

Comment: Cool. Thx. .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess according to [this article](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/12996/when-should-i-use-the-magento-compiler) - the solution for modenr systems is - to turn it off and utilize opcode caching