# Fatal Error on Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Configurable.php

Tags: configurable-product, magento-1, error, fatal-error

Anyone experienced this? I still couldn't spot the issue so might as well call for some help.

```
PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getName() on a non-object in /home/site/includes/src/Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Configurable.php on line 704
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was because of the simple products not populated in the stock inventory table. Reindexing `cataloginventory_stock` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I think Magento Compiler is on in your case and that is making problem here.

As **[Community Suggests](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/12996/when-should-i-use-the-magento-compiler)**, avoid using Magento compilation if possible. There are lot of other good and efficient ways to speed up your application.

So as @MikeWhiteby suggested you just re-run the compilation process by going to `System > Tools > Compilation` and clicking ***Run Compilation Process***

Comment: I beleive you should be able to just re-run the compilation process by going to System > Tools > Compilation and clicking 'Run Compilation Process'.

Comment: @MikeWhitby Thanks for that feedback. I updated my answer