# Magento Upgrade: Fatal error: Class 'Magento_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql' not found in /home/xxxxx/public_html/includes/src/__default.php on line 29298

Tags: magento-1.9, php-5.4, compiler

I just updated my magento installation from 1.7 to the latest version via FTP

and now when I try to access the website or the backend I get the error

```
    Fatal error: Class 'Magento_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql' not found in 

/home/xxxxx/public_html/includes/src/__default.php on line 29298
```

Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: just delete the files from `magento root/includes/src` and open the file`inculdes/config.php` comment the 28,29 th lines by #.

Comment: Please read: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/12996/when-should-i-use-the-magento-compiler

Answer (score 2):

As per as your question, i  have see that complier is enable at system.So you should disable the compile before upgrade.After upgrade you need enable compiler

Disable compiler by command prompt

```
php -f shell/compiler.php -- disable
php -f shell/compiler.php -- clear
```

or By file  remove command at stat and add comment src at file **includes/config.php**

```
#define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');
define('COMPILER_COLLECT_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'stat');
```