# In Compilation what task performed by magento

Tags: magento-1.9, compiler

I bought many extension from somewhere.In whole document they mentioned compilation process.
Basically I want to know that magento compilation , what the mean of that and what task being done by magento during compilation process..

Comment: https://www.byte.nl/blog/should-i-use-the-magento-compiler/.. see at

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deepak,basically **compilation process has been  speed up  the system.**

By using Compilation `process magento  reduce Codepool files(local,community,Core),thus make system.`

According compilation,magento is copy it modules core files `at includes/src files`.
This process magento is `only copy active modules code  files(Core,community,local)`

Good describe [at flyingmana answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/12996/when-should-i-use-the-magento-compiler/13007#13007)