# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 unknown column 'e.status' after 1.9.2 Upgrade

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.2.0

We have just updated from 1.90 to 1.92 and the following error is showing...

Any idea how to fix it?

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'e.status' in 'where clause',
query was:
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT e.entity_id) FROM `catalog_product_flat_1` AS `e`
INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index`
ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=1 AND cat_index.category_id = '301' AND cat_index.is_parent=1
WHERE (e.status = 1)


Trace:
#0 public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT COUNT(DI...', Array)
#4 public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT COUNT(DI...', Array)
#5 public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(828): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#6 public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(225): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchOne(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#7 public_html/app/design/frontend/novaworks/bearstore/template/page/html/home-content.phtml(104): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->getSize()
#8 public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('...')
#9 public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/novawo...')
#10 public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#11 public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#12 public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#13 public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('home.content', true)
#14 public_html/app/design/frontend/novaworks/bearstore/template/page/html/header.phtml(117): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('home.content')
#15 public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('...')
#16 public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/novawo...')
#17 public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#18 public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#19 public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#20 public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('header', true)
#21 public_html/app/design/frontend/novaworks/bearstore/template/page/1column.phtml(65): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('header')
#22 public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('...')
#23 public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/novawo...')
#24 public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#25 public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#26 public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#27 public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#28 public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(137): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#29 public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'shop')
#30 public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'shop')
#31 public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()
#32 public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#33 public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#34 public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#35 public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#36 public_html/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#37 {main}
```

Comment: Are you sure the update ran fine? looks like a column is missing is your flat table. Have you tried re-indexing your entire store, flushing cache ...etc after the upgrade?

Comment: we are getting this error but very sporadically. i have tried re-indexing and re-caching and it only resolves the issue temporarily. any ideas other than maybe scheduling this via cron? wouldn't performance be impacted if we did this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It seems a re-indexing issue. Try the following Steps to Re-index:

1. Magento Admin Panel
2. System
3. Index Management
4. Select All
5. Submit (Re-index Data)

---

### Below are steps to follow if you can't login to the Admin Console

...which is probably the case if you're getting that SQL Error when you access any page...

To do perform the following steps, you'll need to be able to ssh into your hosting provider's terminal console.

1. ssh into your webhost provider
2. navigate to the `<magento_root>/shell` folder

   `cd /path/to/magento/installation/folder/shell`
3. Run the indexer to regenerate all indices (this may take a while...)

   `php -f indexer.php reindexall`
4. If you have compilation enabled (and you [probably shouldn't](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/12996/when-should-i-use-the-magento-compiler), but if you DO), then re-compile:

   `php -f compiler.php compile`
5. Clear out all your Magento caches

   `php -f cleanCache.php clean all`

After the above is all said and done then you should have a working installation.  You will be able to login to your Admin Console and the error you mention above should go away.

Comment: Perfect. Reindexed and it's working perfectly now.

Comment: Michael, were you able to login to the admin console and perform these steps?  I couldn't in my testing when I reproduced the error so I updated the accepted answer with steps on how to do it from the command line which I could reproduce and confirm also solved the problem....