# Magento upgrade to 1.9.2

Tags: upgrade, ce-1.9.2.0

I see this error on the product pages only.

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'e.status' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT count(DISTINCT e.entity_id) FROM `report_event` AS `report_table_views`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` ON e.entity_id = report_table_views.object_id AND e.entity_type_id = 4
 INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id='1' AND cat_index.category_id = '393' AND cat_index.is_parent=1 WHERE (report_table_views.event_type_id = 1) AND (logged_at >= '2015-07-09 07:19:10') AND (logged_at <= '2015-07-09 08:19:10') AND (((e.status = '1'))) AND (e.entity_id NOT IN('9846')) AND (e.entity_id NOT IN((SELECT `sales_flat_quote_item`.`product_id` FROM `sales_flat_quote_item` WHERE (quote_id = ''))))
```

I already tried reindexall and cleared the cache but the error still shows. Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: sorry but this is not a duplicate of http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/73641/unknown-column-e-status-after-1-9-2-update. I encountered this error before and it was solved by reindexing. but this error on product pages does not get fix even after reindex and clear cache.

Comment: The error is happening on a different table: catalog_product_entity.

Comment: Agreed this is not the EXACT same problem, though the solution should resolve this related problem also.  Any chance you have compilation enabled?  I updated the accepted answer in the linked question to include more precise instructions that include handling compilation complications as well as executing the steps from the command line which handled all associated errors in my testing.  If it doesn't resolve it, post the entirety of your exception message from `var/reports` & the complete entry from `var/log/system.log` and `var/log/exception.log` somewhere I can download it & I'll help debug