# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 unknown column 'e.status' after 1.9.2 Upgrade. Cannot log in in admin panel

Tags: error, upgrade, ce-1.9.2.0

Due error I cannot log in admin panel and re-index.

Comment: Can you re-index from the command line

Answer (score 2):

This does appear to be a duplicate of [SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 unknown column 'e.status' after 1.9.2 Upgrade](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/73641/sqlstate42s22-column-not-found-1054-unknown-column-e-status-after-1-9-2-up) but since neither provide a direct answer as to how to resolve it when you can't login to the Admin Console backend interface, I thought I'd whip up an answer.

To do the following, you'll need to be able to ssh into your hosting provider's terminal console.

1. ssh into your webhost provider
2. navigate to the /shell folder

   `cd /path/to/magento/installation/folder/shell`
3. Run the indexer to regenerate all indices (this may take a while...)

   `php -f indexer.php reindexall`
4. If you have compilation enabled (and you [probably shouldn't be](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/12996/when-should-i-use-the-magento-compiler), but if you ARE), then re-compile:

   `php -f compiler.php compile`
5. Clear out all your Magento caches

   `php -f cleanCache.php clean all`

After the above is all said and done then you should have a working installation.  You will be able to login to your Admin Console and the error you mention above should go away.

Comment: Someone should add this to the accepted answer for the question for which this one is a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks, primo - thought I couldn't do that until my rep increased, forgot that it just goes into a queue until peer-reviewed.  Updated answer as you suggested.  Waiting on someone with enough rep to review and approve.