# Exception error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'e.status' in 'where clause'

Tags: error

My site stopped working in the last couple days. I think GoDaddy installed the new CE 1.9.2 on the server and now I'm receiving this message

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'e.status' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT e.entity_id) FROM `mage_catalog_product_flat_1` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `mage_report_compared_product_index` AS `idx_table` ON (idx_table.product_id=e.entity_id) AND (idx_table.visitor_id = '65199')
 INNER JOIN `mage_catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=1 AND cat_index.category_id = '2'
 LEFT JOIN `mage_core_store` AS `store_index` ON store_index.store_id = idx_table.store_id
 LEFT JOIN `mage_core_store_group` AS `store_group_index` ON store_index.group_id = store_group_index.group_id
 LEFT JOIN `mage_catalog_category_product_index` AS `store_cat_index` ON store_cat_index.product_id = e.entity_id AND store_cat_index.store_id = idx_table.store_id AND store_cat_index.category_id=store_group_index.root_category_id WHERE (e.status = 1) AND (cat_index.visibility IN(3, 2, 4) OR store_cat_index.visibility IN(3, 2, 4))

Trace:
#0 /home/jdmotorsportsllc/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/jdmotorsportsllc/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/jdmotorsportsllc/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/jdmotorsportsllc/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT COUNT(DI...', Array)
#4 /home/jdmotorsportsllc/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT COUNT(DI...', Array)
#5 /home/jdmotorsportsllc/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(828): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#6 /home/jdmotorsportsllc/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(225): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchOne(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#7 /home/jdmotorsportsllc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Reports/Model/Product/Index/Abstract.php(175): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->getSize()
#8 /home/jdmotorsportsllc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Reports/Model/Product/Index/Abstract.php(202): Mage_Reports_Model_Product_Index_Abstract->calculate()
#9 /home/jdmotorsportsllc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Reports/Block/Product/Abstract.php(186): Mage_Reports_Model_Product_Index_Abstract->getCount()
#10 /home/jdmotorsportsllc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Reports/Block/Product/Compared.php(66): Mage_Reports_Block_Product_Abstract->getCount()
#11 /home/jdmotorsportsllc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Reports_Block_Product_Compared->_toHtml()
#12 /home/jdmotorsportsllc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#13 /home/jdmotorsportsllc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#14 /home/jdmotorsportsllc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#15 /home/jdmotorsportsllc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('right', true)
#16 /home/jdmotorsportsllc/public_html/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/page/2columns-right.phtml(57): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('right')
#17 /home/jdmotorsportsllc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/jdmotorsp...')
#18 /home/jdmotorsportsllc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/rwd/de...')
#19 /home/jdmotorsportsllc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#20 /home/jdmotorsportsllc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#21 /home/jdmotorsportsllc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#22 /home/jdmotorsportsllc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#23 /home/jdmotorsportsllc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(137): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#24 /home/jdmotorsportsllc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#25 /home/jdmotorsportsllc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#26 /home/jdmotorsportsllc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()
#27 /home/jdmotorsportsllc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#28 /home/jdmotorsportsllc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#29 /home/jdmotorsportsllc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#30 /home/jdmotorsportsllc/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#31 /home/jdmotorsportsllc/public_html/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#32 {main}
```

Comment: I reindexed all the data and it seems to be working now but I'm worried something might still be messed up.

Comment: Perform full re-indexation and then clear cache and check.

Answer (score 11):

Hi is related to the tables catalog_flat I would suggest you to disable flat catalog for products and categories in
System -> Configuration -> Catalog
Then do a reindex and the error will go away.

Comment: After reindexing you can try to re-enable the flat catalog and see if now breaks your store or not. If not you are good to go with active flat catalog.

Answer (score 5):

It seems to be indexation issue. 
Perform full re-indexation and flush cache.

Comment: You need to be able to ssh into your hosting provider's terminal console.  

1. ssh into your webhost provider
2. navigate to the `<magento_root>/shell` folder

    `cd /path/to/magento/installation/folder/shell`

3. Run the indexer to regenerate all indices (this may take a while...)

    `php -f indexer.php reindexall`

4. If you have compilation enabled (and you [shouldn't](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/12996/when-should-i-use-the-magento-compiler) ), then re-compile:

    `php -f compiler.php compile`

5. Clear out all your Magento caches

    `php -f cleanCache.php clean all`