# How to revert changes made by patch 6285

Tags: magento-1.8, patches

My current Magento version is 1.8.1.0

By mistake I downloaded and installed wrong version for 6285 named PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.9.1.1_v2-2015-07-08-08-07-43.sh instead of it should be PATCH_SUPEE-6285_CE_1.8.1.0_v1-2015-07-07-09-06-30.sh

While installing the wrong version is has displayed following error:

> ```
> Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
> ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.
>
> patching file app/Mage.php
> patching file app/code/community/Phoenix/Moneybookers/controllers/MoneybookersController.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/AjaxController.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Category/WidgetController.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/DatafeedsController.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/ReviewController.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/WidgetController.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/Block/WidgetController.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/Page/WidgetController.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/PageController.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Cms/WysiwygController.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Customer/System/Config/ValidatevatController.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/JsonController.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/NotificationController.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/CustomerController.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/ProductController.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/ReviewController.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/SalesController.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/ShopcartController.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/TagController.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/ReportController.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Rss/CatalogController.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Rss/OrderController.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Billing/AgreementController.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/View/GiftmessageController.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Recurring/ProfileController.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/TransactionsController.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/Config/System/StorageController.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/TagController.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Tax/RateController.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/TaxController.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Api2/controllers/Adminhtml/Api2/AttributeController.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/controllers/Adminhtml/Bundle/SelectionController.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/controllers/Adminhtml/RefreshController.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Centinel/controllers/Adminhtml/Centinel/IndexController.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/MultishippingController.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Connect/controllers/Adminhtml/Extension/LocalController.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Abstract.php
> Hunk #1 succeeded at 89 with fuzz 2 (offset -6 lines).
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Oauth/controllers/Adminhtml/Oauth/AuthorizeController.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Paygate/controllers/Adminhtml/Paygate/Authorizenet/PaymentController.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/controllers/Adminhtml/Paypal/ReportsController.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Rss/controllers/CatalogController.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Rss/controllers/OrderController.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Widget/Block/Adminhtml/Widget/Chooser.php
> patching file app/code/core/Mage/Widget/controllers/Adminhtml/WidgetController.php
> patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml
> patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/noItems.phtml
> Hunk #1 succeeded at 31 with fuzz 1.
> patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/failure.phtml
> patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/rss/order/details.phtml
> patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/wishlist/email/rss.phtml
> patching file app/design/frontend/default/modern/template/checkout/cart.phtml
> can't find file to patch at input line 907
> Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
> The text leading up to this was:
> --------------------------
> |diff --git app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml
> |index 7bceece..88753c3 100644
> |--- app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml
> |+++ app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml
> --------------------------
> File to patch:
> Skip this patch? [y]
> Skipping patch.
> 1 out of 1 hunk ignored
> patching file downloader/Maged/.htaccess
> patching file downloader/Maged/Controller.php
> Hunk #5 succeeded at 1120 (offset -19 lines).
> patching file downloader/Maged/Model/Session.php
> patching file downloader/lib/.htaccess
> patching file downloader/template/connect/packages.phtml
> patching file downloader/template/connect/packages_prepare.phtml
> patching file downloader/template/login.phtml
> patching file downloader/template/settings.phtml
> patching file errors/processor.php
> ```

The question is - do I need to revert back the patch changes applied by 6285 - manually/automatically? If YES then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either the complete patch is applied or nothing. If the patch scripts show *"ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully."*, no files have been changed and you don't need to revert anything.

If the output would have been *"Patch applied/reverted successfully"*, you could run the patch script again with the `--revert` parameter to revert the changes.

Comment: I was thinking the same but to verify it I just did diff between one file as I have backup of public_html of 3-4 days ago. Please take a look below result.

Comment: ---public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Oauth/controllers/Adminhtml/Oauth/AuthorizeController.php    2015-08-11 00:25:18.000000000 -0500

+++ public_html_6-8-2015/app/code/core/Mage/Oauth/controllers/Adminhtml/Oauth/AuthorizeController.php   2015-08-05 22:07:34.000000000 -0500

@@ -55,7 +55,7 @@
      */
     public function preDispatch()
     {
-        Mage::app()->getRequest()->setInternallyForwarded();
+        $this->getRequest()->setParam('forwarded', true);

Comment: This change comes from SUPEE-5344, not from SUPEE-6285

Comment: oh i see. so i dont need to worry about it and i can move forward to apply the correct patch for 6285, correct?

Comment: Yes. This is correct.

Comment: thank you so much for your help. i really appreciate it :)

Comment: hi there again, i successfully applied all remaining patches. however as per the document when i performed the following step to lock down the permissions my whole site and admin got discontinued. it says "internal server error!"

find . -type d -exec chmod 500 {} \;
find . -type f -exec chmod 400 {} \;
find var/ -type f -exec chmod 600 {} \;
find media/ -type f -exec chmod 600 {} \;
find var/ -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \;
find media/ -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \;

Comment: hello fschmengler, can you please help me with this?

Comment: I don't see how this relates to the patches, sorry.

Comment: well I was referring the pdf - "Installing a Patch for Community Edition" given at https://www.magentocommerce.com/download step #6: point #3 BTW I just resolved it by changing the permission to 755.

Comment: Further if you look at pdf document - step #10 recompile the store (only if compiled) how would I know whether should i run this step or not?

Comment: Go to `System > Tools > Compiler` in the admin panel. The compiler should be disabled. See also: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/12996/when-should-i-use-the-magento-compiler

Comment: I checked it - the compiler status says disabled. however compiler state is compiled. I'm still not sure should i perform this step or not?

Comment: It's not necessary then.