# Should we keep Magento compiler enabled or disabled?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, magento-enterprise, compiler, memcached

I am currently using Magento EE 1.14.2.1 and memcache is also enabled on the server. 
So the question is whether it's worth keeping Magento compiler enabled? I have read online that the compiler can increase website speed by 25% to 50% but I am not sure whether it's good to do it. 
Also, PHP APC is disabled on the server.

Answer (score 1):

The Magento Compilation is a feature that allows you to compile all Magento installation files in order to create a single include path. This feature is designed to improve the performance of your online store and is supposed to give between 25% and 50% increase in your page load speed.

**Note that before making any changes to your Magento Installation files, the Magento compilation feature should be disabled**. To disabe Magento Compilation, go to your Admin Panel -> System -> Tools -> Compilation and click on the Disable button.

if you face problem when compile enable u may take support to magento as Magento EE client

If your issue is for an Enterprise Edition store with a valid Magento Enterprise Edition license, please login to the Magento account linked to the license and open a support ticket for further assistance.

```
To open a support ticket
1) Login to your Magento Commerce account https://www.magentocommerce.com/
2) Go to Support > Open a Ticket
3) Click on Open New Ticket
4) Enter the required information and click Submit
```

The following article will provide you with instruction on adding shared access between accounts:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/sharing-access-to-your-magento-account-for-enterprise-and-community

ref:
https://www.siteground.com/kb/magento-compilation/
[When should I use the Magento Compiler](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/12996/when-should-i-use-the-magento-compiler)