# Recompile the store is necessary after applying the patch 7405?

Tags: ce-1.8.1.0, patches, supee-7405

I need your help to figure out something which I should do or not.
Recently I applied the latest patch 7405 on my Magento store - CE 1.8.1.0 and as per the online PDF doc I did "Flash Cache Storage" from admin as step 9. There is further step 10 which says about "Run Compilation Process".

Is this really necessary to run that step? I'm worried because there is some custom work done on my store so after performing this step is there any possibility to get ruined any of my custom work done?

Please advice.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I wonder nobody have still answered? or is this issue really unknown?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a flow chart:

```
  +---------------------------------+
  |Do you use the Magento Compiler? |
  +--+--------------------------+---+
     |                          |
     | no                       | yes
     |                          |
     |                   +------v----------------+
     |                   |Did you make changes in|
     |       +-----------+compiled files?        |
     |       |           +------------------+----+
     |       |no                            |
     |       |                              |yes
     |       |                              |
     |       |   +--------------------------v--------------+
     |       |   |Sorry, you are screwed. You won't        |
     |       |   |be able to change anything again.        |
     |       |   |Make a backup of the /include directory, |
     |       |   |say goodbye to your customizations and   |
     |       |   |reimplement them properly                |
     |       |   +-----+-----------------------------------+
     |       |         | OK
     |   +---v---------v--------+
     |   |Do you really need it?|  yes
     |   |Please read [1]       +---------------+
     |   +-----+----------------+               |
     |         | no                             |
     |  +------v---------------+                |
     |  | Disable the Compiler |                |
     |  +------+---------------+                |
     |         |                                |
     |         |                                |
+----v---------v-------+               +--------v--------+
|All is good, skip the |               | No worries,     |
|"Run Compilation" step|               | run compilation |
+----------------------+               +-----------------+
```

[1] [When should I use the Magento Compiler](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/12996/when-should-i-use-the-magento-compiler)

Comment: Maybe in his case the easiest way to say "No, just ignore this step" :)

Comment: I disagree. If they use the compiler, this means the shop is still unprotected.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think if he was using it, most likely he should know about it.