# How to solve Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup' not found in /includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup.php error

Tags: magento-1.9, error, eav

Yesterday I changed my index.php file to make it available to the specific IP addresses written in the Developer options of the Admin Panel.

I changed

> if (file_exists($maintenanceFile)) {

to

> if (file_exists($maintenanceFile)   && !(Mage::helper('core')->isDevAllowed())) {

and moved

> require MAGENTO_ROOT . '/app/bootstrap.php';
>
> require_once $mageFilename;

at the top of the changed condition.

My website did what I wanted it to do for the following hours, but when I woke up this morning nothing worked. The error message is

> Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup' not found in /includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup.php

I set the index.php file like it was before the changes but the problem remains the same.

Is there any way I can fix that?

Thanks.

Cg

Comment: Welcome to Magento SE. The path `includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup.php` looks like you are using compilation. Try turning it off. See also: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/12996/when-should-i-use-the-magento-compiler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fschmengler was right.

The solution consisted in disabling compilation.

Do do so, I changed

> includes/config.php

I commented the uncommented line and uncommented the commented line.

Thanks :)