# Magento’s Compilation on 1.9.2.4

Tags: ce-1.9.2.4, compilation

A quite simple question maybe, but should I enable Magento’s Compilation on my 1.9.2.4 install?

Will it improve the speed of my Magento store with 90.000+ products?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you should **not** enable it.

We host many sites and do not have it enabled anywhere.

See this answer for a more in-depth information: [When should I use the Magento Compiler](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/12996/when-should-i-use-the-magento-compiler)

Comment: 2 Days before I enabled Compilation, still now working good, all functions going very well. Advise me any other possibilities of error.