# Magento 1.9 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$od823' (T_VARIABLE) in /var/www/new/includes/src/Zend_Http_Response.php on line 1

Tags: magento-1.9

How to resolve this error?

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$od823' (T_VARIABLE) in /var/www/new/includes/src/Zend_Http_Response.php on line 1

Answer (score 1):

It seems your compiled copy has some errors

Re-download **lib/Zend/Http/Response.php** (or maybe full **lib** folder, or maybe full Magento) for your Magento version

Disable compilation http://www.createhosting.co.nz/support/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=49

Re-enable compilation (if wanted, not sure why would you want to do that, but that's your choice) [When should I use the Magento Compiler](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/12996/when-should-i-use-the-magento-compiler)

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/219000/magento-1-9-3-4-compiler-is-disabled-but-the-compiler-status-is-always-shown-as/219009#219009