# Magento 1.9.3.4 compiler is disabled but the compiler status is always shown as enable. How to resolve it?

Tags: magento-1.9

Magento 1.9.3.4 compiler is disabled but the compiler status is always shown as enable. How to resolve it?

[image]

Comment: What happens if you click on Disable button ?

Comment: backend all menu  disappear when i enable in include or using CLI then every this working fine when run comp then backend gone crash

Answer (score 1):

**app/etc/modules/Mage_Compiler.xml**

Change it to...

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mage_Compiler>
            <active>false</active>
            <codePool>core</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Core />
            </depends>
        </Mage_Compiler>
    </modules>
</config>
```

And clear cache

Comment: After that, verify you have only .htaccess & config.php in includes folder (if not, delete the rest), and comment code in config.php

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$od823' (T_VARIABLE) in /var/www/new/lib/Zend/Http/Response.php on line 1

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/218861/magento-1-9-parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-od823-t-variable-in-var/218869#218869

Answer (score 0):

Using a SSH command you can disable compilation

use below link to disable and know the status of compilation

http://www.createhosting.co.nz/support/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=49