# Is enabling Magento 1.7 compilation worthwhile?

Tags: magento-1.7, pagespeed

I'm trying to speed up my Magento 1.7 installation until we can migrate it over to 2.3. One of the recommendations I've seen is to enable Magento Compilation i.e [here](https://www.shopping-cart-migration.com/carts-reviews/magento/9-surprisingly-impactful-ways-to-speed-up-magento-1-x-2-x). However, on SO I saw that it isn't recommended anymore. [SO](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/12996/when-should-i-use-the-magento-compiler)
So should I use it or not?

Comment: No real gain from enabling it

Comment: Could you post this as an answer with some reasoning behind it please? I'm sure I'm not the only one who was confused by it. thanks!